# Record and replay human-readable protobuf messages using a file with protobuf-csharp-port

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf-csharp-port and I need the ability to record some protobuf messages for replay later. XML would be ideal for me, but I'm flexible as long as a human could go into the file, make changes, then replay the messages from the file.

Using this C# code:

```
        MyRequest req =
            MyRequest.CreateBuilder().SetStr("Lafayette").Build();

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
                };

            var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, xmlWriterSettings);

            ICodedOutputStream output = XmlFormatWriter.CreateInstance(xmlWriter);
            req.WriteTo(output);
            output.Flush();
            string xml = stringWriter.ToString();

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"Requests.txt"))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(xml);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(xml);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(xml);
            }
        }
```

I produce the Requests.txt file containing:

```
<str>Lafayette</str>
<str>Lafayette</str>
<str>Lafayette</str>
```

However when I try to deserialize them back using:

```
        var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
        };

        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"Requests.txt", xmlReaderSettings))
        {
            ICodedInputStream input = XmlFormatReader.CreateInstance(xmlReader);
            MyRequest reqFromFile;

            while(!input.IsAtEnd)
            {
                reqFromFile =
                    ReverseRequest.CreateBuilder().MergeFrom(input).Build();
            }
        }
```

Only one `MyRequest` gets deserialized and the other two are ignored. (After `reqFromFile` is built, `input.IsAtEnd == true`.)

So back to my question: is there some way to read multiple human-readable protobuf messages from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So back to my question: is there some way to read multiple human-readable protobuf messages from a file?

Well you're currently creating a single text file with multiple root elements - it's not a valid XML file.

The simplest approach would probably be to create a single XML document with all those requests in, then load it (e.g. with LINQ to XML) and create an `XmlReader` positioned at each of the root element's children. Each of those `XmlReader` objects should be able to then deserialize to a single protobuf message.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [Protocol buffer Editor](http://code.google.com/p/protobufeditor/)

Alternatively there is Google own Text format which is a bit like JSon. You can convert between the 2 using the protoc command (look at encode / decode options, you also need the proto definition)

Comment: Interesting. If we were using Java, I'd be tempted to look more closely.